# Python pandas dataframe problem for columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a difficulty to add a list of values for dataframe column.
I would like to add column values by ID as line numbering.
For example: ["ID": 4, "Value": "Yes"] to the line 4 of pandas dataframe column['AUTO-INVESTMENT']. Is this possible without loops or how with a loop?
Here is my code:

```
print('Debug starts: ')
for x in df['AUTO-INVESTMENT']:
    df['AUTO-INVESTMENT'] = tmplist3[idx]['Auto-Invest']
    idx += 1
index = 0
index += 1
df.astype(str)
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'./test.csv', index = None, header=True, sep=";", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
for item in tmplist3:
    if item["ID"] in df.index:
        df.loc[item["ID"], "AUTO-INVESTMENT"] = item["Auto-Invest"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem with this is that list index is out of range. I need to add values by ID that works as an row numbering. I have a list tmplist3 which has 'ID' and by that ID I want to insert value Auto-Invest to specific row

Comment: Hi Laurent. This gives me an error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'. And does this add to specifix rows values?

Comment: And my df has NaN values there.

Comment: tmplist3[0] has a value as follows: {'ID': 0, 'ACCOUNTNUM': '222222999999', 'Auto-Invest': 'No', 'AccountProduct': 'WA001'}

Comment: Ok, so this a list of dicts. See my updated answer.

Comment: Many thanks Laurent. This solved the problem. Did not know that you could even do that with loc.

Comment: No pb. If this answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. In any case, have a nice day.